# How to move the ImageView extreme right in android LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

This is my xml. I need to place my icon to extreme right. But it's not moving to extreme right. *`"tri_logo"`* I have given gravity as right. But still not moving to right.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lout_profile_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/top_view_height"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.test.customviews.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgTopProfile"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/profilie_icon_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profilie_icon_size"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/hdr_img_padding"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_profile" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTopProfile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/hdr_name_padding" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tri_logo"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/tri_logo"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

ImageView **tri_logo** is not moving to right.

Comment: share your expected output with question

Comment: Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout

Comment: `horizontal` linear layout will ignore this `android:layout_gravity="right"`

Comment: what's the problem of using relative layout is, when text name goes too long, textTopProfile id overlaps on tri_logo id image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toplayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lout_profile_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.test.customviews.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgTopProfile"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/profilie_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/profilie_icon_size"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/hdr_img_padding"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_profile" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/textTopProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
         />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/tri_logo"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/voyage"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You could use RelativeLayout and then use `layout_alignParentEnd=true`, if you want to stick on to `LinearLayout` try above one

Comment: No. This doesn't give the perfect solution. All three are in different position. I need image in center followed by near text and then tri_logo to extreme right.

Comment: @Walter this is the nearest solution we could do with a `LinearLayout` (which you are using now), as i have mentioned you could use `RelativeLayout` with `layout_alignParentEnd=true` if you are ready switching to `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @Walter if position is the issue then use `android:layout_gravity="right"` in the inner `LinearLayout`, see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Wrap up your `ImageView` in a `RelativeLayout` with `match_parent` width and use
`android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`
like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tri_logo"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/tri_logo"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I need to place this layout below the text id textTopProfile? or outside the parent linear layout which holds textTopProfile and an icon?

Comment: yeah, just remove your `imageView tri_logo` from your layout and paste *this* instead !! @Walter

Comment: I used this. But imgTopProfile and textTopProfile are going to left side :(

Comment: it was on the left side from the beginning , ! @Walter what do you exactly want ? to place tri_logo on right side ryt ?

Comment: imgTopProfile ->center, textTopProfile-> near to the imgTopProfile and tri_logo is right.

Comment: First two are already working. But tri logo i couldn't place it in extreme right.

Comment: this should work, replace **JUST** your imageView with the layout i have provided, dont change the whole layout !! you are doing something wrong !! @Walter

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toplayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lout_profile_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <com.test.customviews.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTopProfile"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profilie_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profilie_icon_size"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/hdr_img_padding"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTopProfile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/tri_logo"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/tri_logo"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is no `android:orientation="horizontal"` in `RelativeLayout`. Now the view would be vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tools a LinearLayout provides. Give weight to your child views and change the parent layout's gravity to right

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelatiVeLayout` as immediate parent .

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toplayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lout_profile_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/top_view_height"
        android:clickable="true"
        >

        <com.test.customviews.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTopProfile"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profilie_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profilie_icon_size"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/hdr_img_padding"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTopProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tri_logo"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgTopProfile"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/hdr_name_padding" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tri_logo"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/tri_logo"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```